# Found a user with zero activity having 101 rep

Tags: support, reputation, users

Just for curiosity, I just found a [user on ELL site](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/18318/qpaystaxes) who has zero activity (No question, no answer, no edit, no association on other sites) having 101 rep.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> no association on other sites

In fact, they have: https://stackexchange.com/users/2094462/qpaystaxes?tab=accounts

They just used the "hide communities" feature to hide all non-ELL communities on their profile, so it looks like they only have an account there.

Comment: Ooah! problem solved!

Comment: It also clearly show the association bonus in the reputation tab.

Answer (score 4):

He has [other accounts](https://stackexchange.com/users/2094462/qpaystaxes?tab=accounts). He's simply chosen to hide them on that site.

On the edit tab for your user profile, you see the text

> Hiding a community means other users will not see it in your Communities list and Top Network Posts.